# How to access HTML form input from ASP.NET code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, forms

I have a basic HTML form that gets inserted into a server side *div* tag based on how many records exist in the database. This HTML form comes out just fine, and everything looks good. But on my action page I cannot seem to access the input elements from the code behind. I have tried using the *Request* scope, but I have come up empty on that approach. Any other suggestions?

All of the below suggestions are great, and normally that is what I would do. But these forms are being built on the fly after the page is being compiled, so `runat='server'` did not do anything for me. It just passed that along to the HTML page.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

If you are accessing a plain HTML form, it has to be submitted to the server via a submit button (or via JavaScript post).  This usually means that your form definition will look like this (I'm going off of memory - make sure you check the HTML elements are correct):

```
<form method="POST" action="page.aspx">

    <input id="customerName" name="customerName" type="Text" />
    <input id="customerPhone" name="customerPhone" type="Text" />
    <input value="Save" type="Submit" />

</form>
```

You should be able to access the customerName and customerPhone data like this:

```
string n = String.Format("{0}", Request.Form["customerName"]);
```

If you have `method="GET"` in the form (not recommended - it messes up your URL space), you will have to access the form data like this:

```
string n = String.Format("{0}", Request.QueryString["customerName"]);
```

This of course will only work if the form was 'Posted', 'Submitted', or done via a 'Postback' (i.e., somebody clicked the 'Save' button, or this was done programmatically via JavaScript).

Also, keep in mind that accessing these elements in this manner can only be done when you are not using server controls (i.e., `runat="server"`). With server controls, the id and name are different.

Comment: This was exactly the problem, I was missing the method=post attribute. Thank you much.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for that lately.

Comment: is it possible to also assign values to these controls through Request ?
i got a collection is read only error when attempting to do so .

Comment: I was using only the Id, you need to put the Name or it does not work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to use double quotes i.e. "customerName".  Single quotes do not work.

Answer (score 24):

What I'm guessing is that you need to set those input elements to **runat="server"**.

So you won't be able to access the control

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="myTextBox" />
```

But you'll be able to work with

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="myTextBox" runat="server" />
```

And read from it by using

```
string myStringFromTheInput = myTextBox.Value;
```

Comment: I get `{control} not found in current context` when I do that...

Answer (score 9):

It should normally be done with `Request.Form["elementName"]`.

For example, if you have `<input type="text" name="email" />` then you can use `Request.Form["email"]` to access its value.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way IMO is to include an ID and `runat` server tag on all your elements:

```
<div id="MYDIV" runat="server" />
```

Since it sounds like these are dynamically inserted controls, you might appreciate FindControl().

Comment: Good idea, but it sounds like he is inserting plain HTML; not dynamic controls, so the runat attribute will never get processed

Comment: That right there is the crux of my problem, the runat attribute never gets compiled so I can't access them properly.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using ASP.NET code-behind, add an id to the element and `runat=server`.

You can then reference the objects in the code behind.

Answer (score -1):

You say you're creating a form dynamically - do you really mean a <form> and its contents, because ASP.NET takes issue with multiple forms on a page and it's already creating one überform for you?