# Accessing HTML Checkbox in code behind

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I have a HTML checkbox which will perform a simple validation on another textbox, so the textbox will only be enabled if the checkbox is checked, but I also want to access this checkbox control in code behind to check and uncheck it. I don't think I can use the runat="server" because on the onClick event which will cause ('<%=uitxtVouTypeRedeemValue.ClientID%>') to be output as plain text. Please advice. Thanks.

```
<input type="checkbox" 
 onclick="document.getElementById('<%=uitxtVouTypeRedeemValue.ClientID%>').disabled =(this.checked)?0:1" id="uichkVouTypeRedeemable" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access it from code-behind, you must have runat="server" specified.

To resolve your issue with the onclick event, you can add the following code in your code-behind during the control or page's Load event:

```
uichkVouTypeRedeemable.Attributes.Add("onclick", "document.getElementById('" & uitxtVouTypeRedeemValue.ClientID & "').disabled =(this.checked)?0:1;")
```

Comment: Thanks! A minor correction for others looking at this:
('" & uitxtVouTypeRedeemValue.ClientID & "') should have ' '

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Form data in code behind. See the following Stack Overflow thread :

[How to access html form input from asp.net code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389149/how-to-access-html-form-input-from-asp-net-code-behind)

Essentially, the checkbox checked status will be posted, once the form is submitted. You can then access this information, in the code-behind.

Comment: Hi, besides getting the value, how can I check and uncheck it from code behind?