# How to access HTML controls in source code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have following code in my user control, and I want to access each control in this list either by accessing

or  tag.

```
 <div class="menubarbackground">
    <ul>
        <li id="first" class="heigfbtitle">
            <a href="#" id="firstM" class="teegin mft5">1 First Item</a>
        </li>              
    </ul>
</div>
```

How do I implement the code to access these control in code behind?

Comment: to access plain html code it has to be submitted to the server. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389149/how-to-access-html-form-input-from-asp-net-code-behind

Comment: Use `runat="server"`, which will allow you accessing the element from code-behind using it's Id.

Comment: These are not controls - they are just HTML elements. You need to use `runat="server"` if you want to use them as controls and access them on the server side.