# Asp.net get contents of HTML input box

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have attempted to apply the accepted answer to this question [How to access html form input from asp.net code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389149/how-to-access-html-form-input-from-asp-net-code-behind)

and other similar questions.

I have the following HTML input, that I am using to display a datepicker:

```
FROM:<input type="text" runat="server" name="popupDatepickerFrom" id="popupDatepickerFrom">
```

and this code to then retrieve the value:

```
    string myStringFromTheInput = popupDatepickerFrom.Value;
    Response.Write(myStringFromTheInput);
    Response.End();
```

But this does not return anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you show us the form element?

Comment: And the event handler, for good measure.

Comment: yeah just post the whole html and code behind if it isn't super long

Comment: Knowing the method where you're trying to access the input box would be helpful.

Comment: I just realised, my input was not inside the form tags, your comments prompted me to realise this. Thank you!!

Comment: I added it as a solution if you'd like to mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your input is within a form element, as shown on this page:

[How to access html form input from asp.net code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389149/how-to-access-html-form-input-from-asp-net-code-behind)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
string myStringFromTheInput = Request.Form["popupDatepickerFrom"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the popupDatepickerfrom data like this:

```
string myStringFromTheInput = String.Format("{0}", Request.Form["popupDatepickerFrom"]);
Response.Write(myStringFromTheInput);
Response.End();
```