# Two panels with forms that switch based on radio button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 panels that each have a form. They are hidden at first, and a radio button selection will make 1 panel visible. One is for credit card payments, and the other is for echecks. The code works for this, but there is one glitch. The echeck option first clears the form on submission and then will submit the form in the second click.

How can I get the 2nd panel (checks) to submit the form when it is selected by the radio button for the first time? Does it have to do with Page.IsPostBack or maybe how my if statements are in the Page_Load section?

Here are the 2 radio buttons

```
  <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server"  GroupName="RbPayment" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged" Text="Credit Card" Checked="True" AutoPostBack="True" /> 
  <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" GroupName="RbPayment" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton2_CheckedChanged" Text="Check" AutoPostBack="True" />
```

This is where I have the 2 panels and forms

```
<asp:Panel ID="PanelCard" runat="server" Visible="false" OnLoad="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged">
       <%--Form here--%>
       <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit Payment" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="formbutton" />
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="PanelCheck" runat="server" Visible="false" OnLoad="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged">
       <%--Form here--%>
       <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit Payment" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="formbutton" />
</asp:Panel>
```

I have this code to swap between the panels when a radio button is selected

```
protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RadioButton1.Checked)
        {
            PnlCard.Visible = true;
            PnlCheck.Visible = false;
        }

        if (RadioButton2.Checked)
        {
            PnlCard.Visible = false;
            PnlCheck.Visible = true;
        }

    }

    protected void RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RadioButton1.Checked)
        {
            PnlCard.Visible = true;
            PnlCheck.Visible = false;
        }

        if (RadioButton2.Checked)
        {
            PnlCard.Visible = false;
            PnlCheck.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

This is where I think the problem is but I am not sure what needs to be fixed

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            BtnSubmitCard.PostBackUrl = "https://secure2.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll";
            //Other code here for the form
            }

        if (PnlCard.Visible == true)
        {
            BtnSubmitCard.PostBackUrl = "https://secure2.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll";
            //Other code here for the form
        }

        if (PnlCheck.Visible == true)
        {
            BtnSubmitCheck.PostBackUrl = "https://secure2.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll";
           //Other code here for the form
        }
    }
```

Comment: this sounds like a `IsPostBack` issue.. perhaps you could do this using an UpdatePanel instead this will do partial postbacks

Comment: Are those forms server-side elements? asp.net can only handle 1 server-side form per page. Could this cause your problem?

Comment: @MethodMan Thanks, I just tried this but it won't work because I am using some "input" fields (due to security for payment gateway).

Comment: @Sami Both forms do submit correctly. It is just that on page load, the 2nd panel's submit button clears the form on the 1st click. On the 2nd click, it submits the form just fine.

Comment: do you have enabled viewstate set to true..? prehaps you can store the value in a session or View object and re-assign on that load

Comment: @MethodMan I have AutoPostBack="True" ... is there a viewstate I need to do as well as this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code side appears to be solid, but as was suggested by the first comment, this is indeed a postback issue.  You need to use an UpdatePanel for each of the sections to change visibility on the fly like that, see below:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Panel ID="PanelCard" runat="server" Visible="false" OnLoad="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged">
   <%--Form here--%>
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit Payment" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="formbutton" />
   </asp:Panel>
   <asp:Panel ID="PanelCheck" runat="server" Visible="false" OnLoad="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged">
   <%--Form here--%>
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit Payment" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="formbutton" />
</asp:Panel>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Optionally, you could use two separate update panels as opposed to one large one as well, simply wrap each of the standard panels in an update panel.  This will reduce the amount of data being partially posted back each time.

EDIT: Also you'll need to add a script manager to the page if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way for it to work with "input" fields? I cannot use asp fields (asp textbox and such) because it submits to the server, which poses security risks for the payments.

Comment: @SummerDays look at this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389149/how-to-access-html-form-input-from-asp-net-code-behind

Comment: Thank you! Got it to work. Also I added `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>` which is required for the UpdatePanel.

Comment: Also, I had to add one more line to my Page_Load. I needed both buttons listed under `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` so I added BtnSubmitCheck.

Comment: Added a note about adding a script manager, in case anyone else happens to stumble across this in the future.