# how to access html tags on behind in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net

I have problem in access to  in "table" in "for circle" in code behind.
This is my code behind:

```
protected virtual void showAllBooks()
{
    DataSet.View_bookDataTable oView_bookDataTable = new DataSet.View_bookDataTable();
    DataSetTableAdapters.View_bookTableAdapter oView_bookTableAdapter = new DataSetTableAdapters.View_bookTableAdapter();
    oView_bookTableAdapter.Fill(oView_bookDataTable);
    string forTable = "";  
    int BookCount = oView_bookDataTable.Count; 
    string StartTable = "<table id='tblDelete'>" +
                       "<thead>" +
                          "<tr >" +
                             "<th data-field='checkbox'> select</th>" +
                             " <th data-field='id'>row</th>" +
                             " <th data-field='id'>book code</th>" +
                          "</tr>" +
                       "</thead>" +
                       "<tbody>";
    for (int i = 0; i < BookCount i++)
    {
        DataSet.View_bookRow oViewBookRow = oView_bookDataTable[i];
        forTable += "<tr id='tr+"+i+"'>" +
           string.Format("<td class='center-align'>{0}</td>" +
                     "<td class='center-align'>{1}</td>" +
                     "<td class='right-align'>{2}</td>" ,
                     "<input type='checkbox' id='filled"+ i +"'  runat='Server'/>",
                     i + 1,
                     oViewBookRow.bookID)+
             "</tr>";
    }
    string endTable = " </tbody>" +
                       "</table>";
    string Finally = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", StartTable, forTable, endTable);
    lblBooks.Text = Finally;

}
```

Now I don't know how to access these tags by id or etc to use for example: which rows check boxes checked to insert?

Comment: Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you able to display that table on the page? or you are looking for how to add this table on asp.net page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use checkbox in **html form** and then send data to server.
[example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389149/how-to-access-html-form-input-from-asp-net-code-behind)

This is covered in the [W3C HTML 4 recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html) :

> Checkboxes (and radio buttons) are on/off switches that may be toggled by the user. A switch is "on" when the control element's checked attribute is set.**When a form is submitted,** only "on" checkbox controls can become successful.

i hope to be helpful for you

Comment: Thank you Mr @HosseinAbdi for answer, excuse me that I can't vote your answer because I haven't enough reputation. :)

Answer (score 0):

I usually add runat="server" on my tag. This way I can call it from code behind. I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you, but this is no Html Page, This's code behind and this work not possible.